# How to pass $(this) jquery object

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

What I am trying to implement is like

1) I have one box which contains 1 item with remove icon

2) Click of remove icon I ap showing confirmation box build with boostrap model

3) Click of "Yes" I am removing item from box

Now the problem is like **how can i pass $(this) of first remove icon** ???

Code for remove is like

```
<a class="removepromo pull-left" data-code-name="test" data-rel="21468" href="javascript:void()">
<i class="fa fa-remove remove-btn" title="Remove Promo"></i>
</a>
```

Now on the click of yes from model I want all the attributes of remove button

and here the click event binding of both (remove icon and model yes button) is different so how to pass $(this) object ???

**Current Solution**

I can post an answer because that's one of the ugliest ways to achieve it, that's what I think

```
$('body').on('click','.apply_promo_code',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var url = $(this).data('href');
// open model code, where I have taken yes and no button
//Code for yes button is like :
var btn ='<div data-ref="'+url+'" class="btn confirm-btn confirm-left-btn removepromo_yes">Yes</div>';
return false;
} 

$('body').on('click','.removepromo_yes',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var url = $(this).data('ref');
 // all other stuff
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried doing this using jQuery? If so, can you show us the code

Comment: How is the Modal being invoked? is it some sort of a plugin you are using to display the modal?

Comment: let me share that code as well

Comment: I have added current solution in current solution

Answer (score 0):

**save $(this) in a variable and use onclick function in another method like this:**

```
$('.apply_promo_code').on('click',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
  var removeObject=$(this);     
 $('.removepromo_yes').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var url =removeObject.data('href')    
})
 return false;
} )
```

**there is no problem if you define onClick handlere of your yes button in previous function**

Comment: what u did here i didnt get it

Answer (score 0):

**you can add function and pass this as a parameter**

```
<a class="removepromo pull-left" data-code-name="test" data-rel="21468" href="javascript:void()" onclick="onremove(this)">
<i class="fa fa-remove remove-btn" title="Remove Promo"></i>
</a>



  function onremove(val){
          console.log(val) 
         // val will give you current anchor tag so you can do whatever you want to do
    }
```

Comment: You didnt get my question, On the click next button i want attributes of first lnk

Comment: in you above quetion you have not metioned about next link you said you click on remove icon modal opens and after confirmation you want to delete the attributes right?